# How to run backgroundworker on timer

Tags: c#

Is it possible to run backgroundworker to a timer that you get from toolbox? Just like the Task class can be called on Timer for example:

```
 private void elapsed_time(object sender, Eventargs e)
 {
     Task test = new Task(()=>method());
     test.Start();
 }
```

Maybe this is pretty dumb question but I'm just trying to know. I did research on the internet but no direct answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you mean `Task test`? The constructor seems to be wrong!

Comment: Thank you. but I was wondering if its okay if I only drop  backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); on a timer?

Comment: _" I was wondering if its okay if I only drop backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); on a timer?"_ -- what happened when you tried? _Did_ you try it? If not, why are you spending time writing Stack Overflow posts when you could be _trying it_? There's no fundamental reason you can't execute any code you want in a timer callback/event handler, but for any given code there may be _specific_ reasons it won't work in that particular scenario. If you don't share all the pertinent details, and explain why you need someone else to answer the question, it's not possible to give a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not pretty much sure if your question means to create a Background worker on every tick. But, if that is what you are looking for, I think it is possible! I have not tried this code yet but just guessing it might work:

```
private void elapsed_time(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
     System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

     worker.DoWork += NewBackgroundWork_Start;
     worker.RunWorkerCompleted += NewWork_Completed;
     worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void NewBackgroundWork_Start(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     Console.Writeline("I am the new job");
}

private void NewWork_Completed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     Console.Writeline("The job is complete");
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

You should read the article on MSDN about Timer class.
There is an example, which does exactly what you want:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Just dragging and dropping a timer from the toolbox isn't enough.

The timer has the event `Elapsed` which you can bind a method to. This will execute when the timer goes off.
Best is to see how it works in the Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx